# How to Generate PDF file from .docx from linux server?

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-generation, docx

We use on our production server: Ubuntu 10 server edition.
We need to create a document that includes text , images and  tables in the content  and images in header and footer.
Now we use http://phpword.codeplex.com/ to create  it and it does a great job generating docx files but we need the pdf version of  that file.
How can we convert the docx to pdf ? Or any other library to generate pdf files that allows images in header /footer ?
Using windows components is not a solution.
Using openOffice maybe? can it be used on an ubuntu server edition ?
any other convertor for docx to pdf in linux - server environment ?

Comment: Instead of going from `docx -> pdf` why not directly generate PDF with [`TCPDF`](http://www.tcpdf.org/) ?

Comment: I will try the TCPDF library. Its a good solution if it support all our requirments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your documents include images using OpenOffice is definitely a good solution. Check out [PyODConverter](http://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter) if you want to try this out.

If it's simple text you might want to consider using a simpler solution like PHPDocx, unoconv, AbiWord or LiveDocx.

I've used OOo in the past for this (and still use to convert Odt files to Pdf) and it works great. :)
I only got one problem with it, but has already been resolved. You can check that out here: [Docx to pdf using openoffice headless way too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504308/docx-to-pdf-using-openoffice-headless-way-too-slow)

EDIT:

I've created a bash script "/etc/init.d/openoffice" to start openoffice with the correct options. The file contents are the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# openoffice.org headless server script
#
# chkconfig: 2345 80 30
# description: headless openoffice server script
# processname: openoffice

OOo_HOME=/usr/lib/openoffice
SOFFICE_PATH=$OOo_HOME/program/soffice

if [ "$1" == "start" ]; then
 echo "Starting OpenOffice headless server"
 $SOFFICE_PATH --headless --accept="pipe,name=beubi_OOffice;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" --invisible --norestore --nodefault --nolockcheck --nofirstwizard
 exit
fi

if [ "$1" == "stop" ]; then
 echo "Stopping OpenOffice headless server."
 killall -9 soffice.bin && killall -9 soffice
 exit
fi

echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
exit 1
```

Then just set execute permission on it and you should be ready to go.

Comment: The problem is that we use ubuntu SERVER edition ( no GUI, just console), Can OpenOffice run just in console ?

Comment: Sure. But it needs to run in headless mode and with some other options like "-nofirststartwizard".

I've a little script to start/stop it as a service. I'll edit my previous answer and post it there since in this comment I don't have enough space.

Answer (score 1):

You could try docx4j (Java). It can generate pdfs, and images in headers shouldn't be a problem.

**Update May 2016**

For the last year or so, we've been offering a high quality commercial docx to PDF converter which runs on Linux (and Solaris for that matter); try it at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/ where you can also download an installer.

Comment: If TCPDF fails , I will try docx4j.

Comment: docx4j and xdocreport fail on complex templates

Comment: @Mark report any docx4j failure at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/data-binding-java-f16/

Comment: You can use [Carbone](https://carbone.io) to create pdf for docx easily